# How to properly copy fa CSV file from one folder to another and convert it go GS?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

So I've been trying to write a script, which is doing that with partial success.

The problem is that this script is misbehaving for unknown reasons(to me).

Currently, it copies(or adds) the files from the source to the destination folder. Then it converts the newly added file from CSV to GS and finally deleted the copied CSV.

The problem is that when it deletes the copied CSV it deletes it from both the source and the destination folders, and I want to delete it just from the destination folder.

Finally, I end up with only the converted csv(now GS) in both folders and **what I want to achieve** is simply to keep the original file in the original folder in its original format and have the google sheet in the destination folder.

Can somebody please help me?

Here's what I have :

```
    function copyFilesToFolder (latestFileIdString, folderId) {

    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(latestFileIdString);




    DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).addFile(file);

    convertToGS(folderId)  

    } 

  function convertToGS(folderId) {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();

    Drive.Files.copy({}, file.getId(), {convert: true});//convert CSV to SS

    Drive.Files.remove(file.getId());//remove CSV


    //appendNewToDashboardSS(folderId);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

### Modification points :

- [`addFile()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#addFile(File)) is used for adding a parent to a file. By this, the file has 2 parents. This means that one file ID has 2 folder IDs. So when one file of 2 folders is removed, both files are removed.
- When it copies a file, please use [`makeCopy()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy(Folder)).

### Modified part :

#### From :

```
DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).addFile(file);
```

#### To :

```
file.makeCopy(DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId));
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Robert Ross Welcome. Thank you, too.